# How to embed Document Library in .NET Application same like embedding in Microsoft teams?

Tags: document-library, asp.net, embedded

In Microsoft Teams, when we add a document library into the tab, it embed only Document Library, no Other portion like Header or side bar of SharePoint is visible.

I want to embed the same like in my custom .NET application.

Is it possible to include only Document Library in .NET application?

Comment: Hi Vikash, as i understand when we add a a Document Library into the new Tab, it does not embed a Document Library. it creates separate UI which is built for Microsoft Teams only and backend of this Library is still in SharePoint Document Library. In custom application you want to embed Document Library,still you can use Iframe and embed. use different CSS may be to hide another Component

Comment: Sounds good as action plan. Let me re-think on this approach. Thanks for your input.